# Layout Builder & linking fields

Tags: layout-builder

I'm using Drupal 9.

I have a paragraph type which consists of 4 fields:

1. Image
2. Title
3. Text
4. Link Field

I'm using layout builder to display the paragraph.

I want the Image, title & Text to all be clickable, and click through to the Url set in the Link field (#4).

How do I do this?

Comment: Theme the paragraph type with the desired markup? Have you done that?

Comment: No, I was convinced there would be a way of doing it through the UI without any custom code

Comment: I do not know of a way to do this without any custom coding. I personally would add a template for the paragraph type, and add an anchor link to the end of it, that I would then use CSS to cover the entire element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this, I created a custom module for my project:

1. Create the custom module file (if it doesn't already exist)

[PROJECT-ROOT]/web/modules/custom/[PROJECT-NAME]_paragraphs/[PROJECT-NAME]_paragraphs.module

2. Create the function to check if this particular paragraph type has a field called "field_link" (the machine name of whatever your field is called).  If it has the field, store the URL in a variable called "$link_uri"

   ```
        function [PROJECT_NAME]_paragraphs_preprocess_paragraph(&$variables) {
      /** @var \Drupal\paragraphs\ParagraphInterface $paragraph */
      $paragraph = $variables['paragraph'];
      if ($paragraph->hasField('field_link')
        && $uri = $paragraph->get('field_link')->uri){
        try {
          $variables['link_uri'] = $paragraph->get('field_link')->uri;
        }
        catch (\Throwable $ex) {
          // Do nothing.
        }
      }
    }
   ```
3. Override the default paragraph template file:

- Create a new file: web/themes/custom/[PROJECT-NAME]/templates/paragraphs/paragraph.html.twig
- Find the default paragraph structure & Copy the default template structure into your new file:
- - web/modules/contrib/paragraphs/templates/paragraph.html.twig

4. Customise it to add the wrap-around anchor tag and populate the href attribute with the variable we just saved ("$link_uri")

For example, my new template is now:

```
{%
  set classes = [
    'paragraph',
    'paragraph--type--' ~ paragraph.bundle|clean_class,
    view_mode ? 'paragraph--view-mode--' ~ view_mode|clean_class,
    not paragraph.isPublished() ? 'paragraph--unpublished'
  ]
%}
{% block paragraph %}
  <div class="para-wrapper">
  {% if link_uri %}
    <a href="{{ link_uri }}">
  {% endif %}
  <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
    {% block content %}
      {{ content }}
    {% endblock %}
  </div>
  {% if link_uri %}
    </a>
  {% endif %}
  </div>
{% endblock paragraph %}
```

Comment: Note - in the code above, I use "$variables['link_uri'] = $paragraph->get('field_link')->uri;"

This works fine for external links (eg: google.com)  but internal links were being output as "entity:node/12345"  Which didn't work, so I've swapped that line for: 

$variables['link_uri'] = $paragraph->get('field_link')->first()->getUrl()->toString();